# Google Datastudio multiple repartitions and types chart

Tags: charts, series, looker-studio

I'm using Google Datastudio and I'm blocked on something weird.

I want to make a chart with globally series and detailed series.

But to do that I have 2 different repartitions and I don't know how to do that.
This is a sample of my data set:

| Type | Detail | Country | Value | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| type1 |  | uk | 60 000 | 2018-12-04 |
| type2 | detail-1 | uk | 15 000 | 2018-12-04 |
| type2 | detail-2 | uk | 11 000 | 2018-12-04 |
| type2 | detail-3 | uk | 4 500 | 2018-12-04 |
| type1 |  | usa | 78 000 | 2018-12-04 |
| type2 | detail-1 | usa | 40 000 | 2018-12-04 |
| type2 | detail-2 | usa | 17 000 | 2018-12-04 |
| type2 | detail-3 | usa | 11 5000 | 2018-12-04 |

I want a series base on "Type" and another on "Detail", then I should use filter for different countries.

How can I do that? I spent a lot of time on this simple problem, but I can't achieve this.

My data comes from SQL Cloud for MySQL

It would be something like this :

[image]

Comment: Can you give us an example of what your output should look like?

Comment: @Bobbylank added to the thread thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your data you need to create and use a 3rd dimension

```
case when Detail is null then Type else Detail end
```

or if Detail actually = '' then

```
case when Detail = '' then Type else Detail end
```

or to be sure

```
case when Detail is null or Detail = '' then Type else Detail end
```

Comment: sorry but I don't know where to use this queries ... ?

Comment: No problem. When you create you graph, your data source will have an edit button next to it (looks like a pencil) in the side panel. Click that and then on the right hand side you'll see 'add a field'. Select that and then enter a name for your dimension and paste in the query. Save it and it'll be available as a dimension for you to use.

Comment: I don't have this pencil, I can click on data source but can't edit it.

Comment: I take it it isn't a data source you created then? The owner needs to give you edit access to the data source or the owner will need to create the dimension

Comment: Thanks ! I have what I want now